# Resize a QWidget containing a QVBoxLayout in runtime when contents are partially Hidden

Tags: qt, dynamic, resize, runtime, qwidget

In this application, a list of HBoxLayouts is generated and put into a VBoxLayout in order to form a dynamically filled list of commands.  There is a button above each sub-list which has the capability to hide the controls below it.  The problem: when a sub-list is hidden, the widget which contains the broadest VBoxLayout does not change in size! The VBoxLayout then stretches to compensate.  I want the container widget to shrink when it contains fewer items!
 It looks like this:

The problem is, when I hide a list under one of the PushButtons, the containing widget won't shrink! the VBoxLayout just expands when there are less visible items :(

Here is a picture of how I see my little GUI.

Here is some code from the broader layout setup:

```
scrollArea = new QScrollArea(this);
scrollAreaLayoutWidget = new QWidget(scrollArea);
scrollAreaLayout = new QVBoxLayout(scrollAreaLayoutWidget);
//scrollAreaLayout is filled with all the stuff you see inside the scroll area...
scrollArea->setWidget(scrollAreaLayoutWidget);
```

I have tried changing the QSizePolicy of the container widget (blue box) in a number of ways.  I've found dozens of resizing questions but I have somehow not discovered an answer. Is there a magic auto-resize setting that I'm missing? 
Let me know if this is painfully vague or incomplete.
Any comment is welcome!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I auto-adjust the size of a QDialog depending on the text length of one of its children?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1675499/how-do-i-auto-adjust-the-size-of-a-qdialog-depending-on-the-text-length-of-one-o)

Answer (score 0):

Turns out all I had to do was create a custom SLOT for when the button that hides part of the Ui is clicked and hide the relevant widget within that function. In the same function, I called `[containerWidget]->adjustSize();` and it did exactly what I was looking for.