# adjust size of QDialog make it to shrink everything

Tags: qt, qt4

Using Qt Designer, I created a `QDialog` which contains two `QGroupBox`s. In one of them, there is a Check Box (`QCheckBox`) that can `setVisible` the other Group Box. 
This works fine that only problem is that I want to be able to resize/adjust the size of the parent dialog accordingly (Regardless of what is the sizes of the two Control Boxes are).
I am familiar with this [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1675499/how-do-i-auto-adjust-the-size-of-a-qdialog-depending-on-the-text-length-of-one-o). The only problem is when I click on Adjust Size, the parent dialog shrinks to be smaller than both group boxes and both boxes disappear. Any other suggestion would be great.

Comment: Are you using a layout?

Comment: @thuga, the two Group Boxes are not in a layout

Comment: Well then adjust size won't work for you, you'll have to do it manually. Adjust size is meant to be used with a layout. Or alternatively, set a layout for your dialog.